# Proof of the formula $x\cdot y=\| x \| \|y\| \cos(\theta)$ for vectors whose dimensions are larger than 3.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we prove the formula $x\cdot y=\| x \| \|y\| \cos(\theta)$  for vectors whose dimensions are larger than 3. All the proofs I saw are given for 2D space using a figure such as the one below.

[image]

Image source: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/dotproduct.aspx

Comment: any couple of vectors in any real vector space can be embedded in a 2D vector space, so it is sufficient to prove it on a plane

Comment: How do you define $x.y$? (as the projection of vector **x** on vector **y**?) In that case, it's just a triangle on a plane you have to consider, since you have only the two vectors **x** and **y**

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 as the sum of the products of vector components.

Comment: God question. There's an answer on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: The bigger question is, how do you define the angle $\theta$?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Given two vectors $u,v$, you can choose the plane $\pi$ containing them. Then you just use the standard definition (the signed length of the arc between $u$ and $v$).

Comment: I think, the answers of @Exodd and tomasz are what I'm looking for, but I need some time to digest them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the cosine rule, which is basis free, and doesn't therefore depend on the orientation of the triangle.

Note that Pythagoras gives us that $|a|^2=\sum a_i^2=\vec a\cdot \vec a$ (we can define this as the dot product of a vector with itself, and it ties up also with the definition of the euclidean norm).

Then the cosine rule tells us that:

$$|\vec a - \vec b|^2=|\vec a|^2+|\vec b|^2 - 2 |\vec a|| \vec b| \cos \theta$$

and we can write this using dot products for equal vectors, which we have just defined:

$$(\vec a - \vec b)\cdot (\vec a - \vec b)=\vec a\cdot \vec a+\vec b \cdot \vec b - 2 |\vec a|| \vec b| \cos \theta$$ so that (expanding the left hand side and cancelling the squares and applying distributive and commutative properties) $$-2\vec a\cdot \vec b= -2 |\vec a|| \vec b| \cos \theta$$

And this justifies the definition of $\vec a\cdot \vec b = |a||b|\cos\theta$

Now, if we expand in orthonormal co-ordinates using Pythagoras we have that $$\vec a \cdot \vec a = \sum a_i^2$$ so that $$(\vec a - \vec b)\cdot (\vec a - \vec b)-(\vec a\cdot \vec a+\vec b \cdot \vec b)=\sum (a_i-b_i)^2-\sum a_i^2-\sum b_i^2=$$$$=\sum \left(a_i^2-2a_ib_i+b_i^2-a_i^2-b_i^2\right)=-2\sum a_ib_i$$ so that we can compute $$\vec a\cdot \vec b=\sum a_ib_i$$ consistently and independent of basis and this joins up all the formulae.

The dot product works because of the cosine rule (which is a generalisation of Pythagoras), and both of these are obviously independent of basis (they depend on lengths and angles). The sum of products form with respect to a basis is not so obviously invariant.

There is a great similarity here with the connection between a quadratic form and the associated symmetric bilinear form (and related constructions) in more general contexts.

Comment: Note that the comment (on the question) on how you define the dot product is relevant here. My answer essentially shows that the properties of the dot product are equivalent to the cosine rule (including invariance under suitable change of basis). The comments also highlight the need to take care as to which of the angles between the vectors (think acute/obtuse) is involved here. What is a definition/explanation/proof will depend on where you start - once the equivalence is proved, either formulation can be used.

Comment: OP specified that he defines dot product as the sum of products of coordinates. The cosine rule is basically equivalent to what he is asking for.

Comment: I agree with @tomasz because then I need the proof of the cosine rule in higher dimensions. I think, the basic difficulty I face here is the notion of an angle in higher dimensions. tomasz and exodd have given answers to defining angle in higher dimensions but need some time to fully digest them.

Comment: @SanyoMn The cosine rule is proved for any triangle. I will amend the answer to show the product of co-ordinates.

Comment: @tomasz I have supplemented my answer with this information, which I almost included anyway. I had missed the "definition" in the comments.

Comment: @MarkBennet: I think your answer would be clearer if you formulated your cosine rule in terms of lengths, writing that $\lVert a-b\rVert^2=\lVert a\rVert^2+\lVert b\rVert^2-2\cos\theta \lVert a\rVert\lVert b\rVert$ and only then converting to the dot product. As is, this is rather obtuse, since it is not clear what "coordinate-free" cosine rule you are referring to, since your statement is not explicitly coordinate free, as it refers to the (not yet proven to be coordinate-free) dot product.

Comment: @tomasz Thanks for your helpful comments. I have rewritten the answer so that it has (I hope) a more logical flow to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it to two dimensions in the following steps:

1. Show that an euclidean isometry preserves angles (and lengths).
2. Show that a linear isometry preserves the dot product.
3. Show that for any vectors $u,v$, there is a linear isometry which takes $u,v$ into the plane spanned by the standard basis vectors $e_1,e_2$.

---

Here is a more fleshed out variant of my answer, using only completely elementary tools.$\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbf R}$

Choose any $n\geq 3$ and let $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ be the standard basis vectors in $\bR^n$. For brevity, given $u,v\in \bR^n$, let us write $u\cdot'v$ for $\lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert\cos(\angle uv)$. The goal is to show that $u\cdot v=u\cdot'v$.

Fix any $j\geq 2$ and $\theta\in \bR$ and consider the rotation $R_{j,\theta}$ by $\theta$ around the subspace spanned by $(e_i)_{i\neq 1,j}$. Explicitly, $R_{j,\theta}(e_1)=\cos\theta e_1+\sin\theta e_j$, $R_{j,\theta}(e_j)=-\sin\theta e_1+\cos\theta e_j$, $R_{j,\theta}(e_i)=e_i$ for $i\neq 1,j$.

Then it is easy to check that for any $j,\theta$ and $u,v\in \bR^n$ we have $R_{j,\theta}(u)\cdot R_{j,\theta}(v)=u\cdot v$. Since $R_{j,\theta}$ is linear, it follwos that it is an isometry, so it preserves lengths and angles, and thus also $R_{j,\theta}(u)\cdot' R_{j,\theta}(v)=u\cdot' v$.

Note also that if $u\in \bR^n$, then we can choose $\theta$ such that $R_{j,\theta}(u)\cdot e_j=0$.

Using this, given any $u,v\in \bR^n$, by applying $R_{j,\theta}$ for $j=2,3,\ldots, n$(and appropriate $\theta$) to $u$ and $v$, we obtain $u',v'$ such that $u'=\alpha e_1$, $u\cdot v=u'\cdot v'$ and $u\cdot' v=u'\cdot' v'$. By applying $R_{2,\pi/2}$, we obtain then $u'',v''$ such that $u''=\alpha e_2$ and both dot products are still the same.

Then we apply successive rotations $R_{j,\theta}$ for $j=3,4,\ldots, n$ (note that all of these preserve $u''$, obtaining a $v'''=\beta e_1+\gamma e_2$ such that $u\cdot v=u''\cdot v'''$ and $u\cdot' v=u''\cdot v'''$.

Now, $u'',v'''$ are in the plane, and so (by knowing that in the plane, $\cdot$ and $\cdot'$ coincide), we conclude that
$$
u\cdot v=u''\cdot v'''=u''\cdot' v'''=u\cdot ' v.
$$

Comment: Doing the second of these looks to be at least as difficult as the original problem.